# CSV loading large amount of data into Pig

Tags: csv, apache-pig

Am using this query in pig to load data from a CSV file with 50000 records in it.

```
A = LOAD '/home/user/q2.csv' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage(',', 'YES_MULTILINE') as (Id:chararray,
PostTypeId:chararray, 
AcceptedAnswerId:chararray, 
ParentId:chararray, 
CreationDate:chararray, 
DeletionDate:chararray, 
Score:chararray, 
ViewCount:chararray, 
Body:chararray, 
OwnerUserId:chararray, 
OwnerDisplayName:chararray, 
LastEditorUserId:chararray, 
LastEditorDisplayName:chararray, 
LastEditDate:chararray, 
LastActivityDate:chararray, 
Title:chararray, 
Tags:chararray, 
AnswerCount:chararray, 
CommentCount:chararray, 
FavoriteCount:chararray, 
ClosedDate:chararray, 
CommunityOwnedDate:chararray);
```

Here is the query to clean the data of \n & , in the body field and few more.

```
Q2Clean = FOREACH Q2 GENERATE
Id as Id, 
PostTypeId as PostTypeId, 
AcceptedAnswerId as AcceptedAnswerId, 
(chararray)REPLACE(ParentId,'"','')  as ParentId, 
CreationDate as CreationDate, 
(chararray)REPLACE(DeletionDate,'"','') as DeletionDate, 
Score as Score, 
ViewCount as ViewCount,  
(chararray)REPLACE(REPLACE(Body,'\n',''),',','')as Body, 
OwnerUserId as OwnerUserId, 
(chararray)REPLACE(OwnerDisplayName,'"','') as OwnerDisplayName, 
LastEditorUserId as LastEditorUserId, 
(chararray)REPLACE(LastEditorDisplayName,'"','') as LastEditorDisplayName, 
LastEditDate as LastEditDate, 
LastActivityDate as LastActivityDate, 
(chararray)REPLACE(Title,',','') as Title, 
(chararray)REPLACE(Tags,',','') as Tags, 
AnswerCount as AnswerCount, 
CommentCount as CommentCount, 
FavoriteCount as FavoriteCount, 
(chararray)REPLACE(ClosedDate,'"','') as ClosedDate, 
(chararray)REPLACE(CommunityOwnedDate,'"','') as CommunityOwnedDate;
```

The problem now is when i store the output its showing 617538 rows written. It has created two files. The first file has 27000 records which are properly formatted but the second file is not stored properly. It contains around 610000 lines and many lines with just , in it. How to load the data properly so that the output shows 50000 instead of 617538 rows.

[Here's the load status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hThW8.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the below part of your script.

```
(chararray)REPLACE(REPLACE(Body,'\n',''),',','')as Body,
```

You have to add another backslash to replace '\n'

```
(chararray)REPLACE(REPLACE(Body,'\\n',''),',','')as Body,
```

Comment: I tired with another backslash to replace \n but still its showing the same number of records.

Comment: @user6118910 Can you post sample data?